# Missing required Icon file 120*120

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, submission

In my application , I added an icon file named "Icon-60@2x.png" it's an 120*120 png picture.
When I try to submit my app in the AppStore I receive :

```
"Missing required icon file . The bundle does not contain an app icon for Iphone/Ipad Touch of exactly '120*120' pixels in .png format for IOS versions >=70"
```

Comment: How did you add the icon?

Comment: I added it on resources folder as all the other icons @rmaddy

Comment: Why aren't you using an asset catalog for your app icons? It is so much easier and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to use the Xcode File menu to add this file to your Project, and then add the file name to your Target's info plist in the array with the all the other icon file names.  Make sure the checkbox for the file in the Assistant for your Target is checked.

Or you can use an asset catalog for all your app's icons.